# Is a flow cancelled if an exception happens

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am experimenting a bit with flows in kotlin and asked myself a question: Will my flows be cancelled if one of the operations within the flow throws an exception even If I use .catch?

If not, how can I cancel my flow when an exception occurs even while using .catch?

### Example

```
fun testFlow() = flow {
   emit("Test")
   emit(Exception("Error"))
   emit("Test2") // This should not be emitted
}.catch { e -> println("Showing UI $e") }
```

### Another Example

```
fun testFlow2() = flow {
   emit("Test")
   throw Exception("Error")
   emit("Test2") // This should not be emitted
}.catch { e -> println("Showing UI $e") }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the execution of the Flow *throws* an Exception, it will cancel and complete the Flow during collection. The `collect()` function call will throw the Exception if the `Flow.catch` operator was not used.

If you *emit* an Exception like in your example, it's just another object in the Flow. Since you have not specified the Flow's type, it's implicitly choosing a type that's common between String and Exception. I think you have a `Flow<Serializable>` since that's a common supertype of both. If you had specified `Flow<String>`, it would not allow you to emit an Exception.

Comment: I've added another example, that should make things clear. But you are right, when an Exception is thrown within the flow, the rest of it does not get executed. Thank you.

Comment: @Tenfour04 is there a way to keep the flow listening, as with JavaRx's Flowable? I have in mind calling collect in a new context that won't cancel the parent, but ain't sure that it will work